# How to execute code after the jquery.validate validation event?

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate 1.9 and wish to execute code every time the form automatically validates (using the default behavior).

I hoped there would exist an OnValidated event I could hook into, but can not find one.

After validation executes I wish to conditionally enable other parts of the page if the form is valid, and disable otherwise.

How would one go about adding a method call following the existing validate() function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery validate 1.8.1, but you should still be able to accomplish this using the valid() function.

valid() will either validate the entire form if you pass it the form ID or individual fields if you pass their respective ID's. It will then return a Boolean based on if they are all valid or not.

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tab1Validation(){
    if($('#field1, #field2, #field3').valid()){
        //Logic if all fields valid - eg: $('#NextTab').show();
    }else{
        //Logic if one or more is invalid
    }
}
</script>

<form id="yourform">
     <div>
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />              
        <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" />              
        <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" />   
    </div>
    <input name="nextTab" type="button" value="Next Tab" onClick="tab1Validation();" />
</form>
```